# values in a table. js jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get data in a table (from db) if they fall between the table header dates. Everything is working except that I am not able to get data between certain dates. Please look on the comments n pic for more info. Help will be greatly appreciated.

```js
//please look at the comments for more information
  
  //this is the info from table header which shows current week dates (in the pic)
  var wkly = document.getElementById("test1").innerHTML; //06/04/2017
    
  var wkend = document.getElementById("test2").innerHTML; //06/10/2017

 
   //values from db "testvalues" which is an array (strings)
    //testvalues[i+2] is a date from db
    for (var i = 0; i < (testvalues.length-1); i = i + 5) {
    
    //this is logic i am trying to show: if dates matches show all the data between those two dates(wkly and wkend) in a table
    if(testvalues[i+2]==wkly && testvalues[i+2]==wkend){ //this is not working
    
    //my code to show data in a table
    }
    
    
    }
```

Comment: `testvalues[i+2]==wkly && testvalues[i+2]==wkend` : the same value(`testvalues[i+2]`) can't be equal to two different things(`wkly`and `wkend`) at the same time.

Comment: What types are in the `testvalues` array? More strings in `mm/dd/yyyy` format, `Date` objects, something else entirely? Can't really answer without knowing that.

Comment: testvalues are strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a high level, you can try something like this. You need to convert your strings into `Date` objects and compare them. I would HIGHLY recommend using a library like [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/) instead though if you are doing any serious date usage in your application.

```js
var wkly = new Date("06/04/2017");
var wknd = new Date("06/10/2017");
var test = new Date("06/07/2017");

function dateInRange(d, start, end){
  return end >= d && start <= end;
}

if(dateInRange(test, wkly,wknd)){
  console.log("in range");
  //...
}else{
  console.log("not in range")
  //...
}
```

If it were me, I would use momentjs and do something like this instead. You can make use of the handy `ìsBetween` function, and explicitly declaring the expected date format is safer(for example, I assumed your dates are in June since it's June right now and you're in America, but in my country I would naturally read them as being in April/October- the format isn't clear. So it helps avoid problems to just declare it).

```js
var wkly = moment("06/04/2017", "MM/DD/YYY");
var wknd = moment("06/10/2017", "MM/DD/YYY");
var test = moment("06/07/2017", "MM/DD/YYY");

if(test.isBetween(wkly, wknd)){
  console.log("in range");
  //...
}else{
  console.log("not in range")
  //...
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi first option is working for me but the only issue is its working month wise i.e. my table is showing all the data from june but i need a data (within a dates in the header). please help.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to say, sorry.

Comment: currently my table header has date (6/4/2017-6/10/2017) , i was trying to get all the data that lies between the  dates shown in the header(start date 6/4 and end 6/10).

Comment: So you can't get the values for `wkly` and `wkend`? If that's the case, it's just some simple string manipulation to extract it from the header text : `var a = "(6/4/2017-6/10/2017)".slice(1,-1).split("-"); var wkly = a[0], wknd = a[1];`

Comment: I am sorry if i did not explained better. I am getting values as expected but i am getting all the values (june1-june30), however i just need to get values from(6/4/17-6/10/17). only those values that falls in between table header dates . on the other hand i need to show only current week values in a table not for the full month

Comment: So just use the if statement? Get all the values in the month, loop through them, and only add one to the table if `dateInRange` is true. If you want more detailed help with that you need to show your actual code for how you're creating the table(probably in a new question).

Comment: Karl at least I got something started thx for such a grt help:)